# Integrability of a a.e. convergent Fourier sum

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Most book discuss whether the Fourier series of a function converges. However, I could not easily find many converse statements, that is, when it does converge, what is the property of the limiting function.

Consider the Fourier series $\sum_k c_k e^{2\pi i k}.$ If it converges a.e. to some function, must the function be Lebesgue integrable? What are some results of this kind?

Comment: $\sum \frac {\sin (nx)} {\ln (n+1)}$ converges for evey $x$ but it is not the FS of any $L^{1}$ function. This question appears often and I just answered it yesterday.